# Getting Cplex example to run: Undefined references

Tags: c++, cplex

I am trying to get the Cplex basic LP example to work. The code can be found [here](https://www.tu-chemnitz.de/mathematik/discrete/manuals/cplex/doc/getstart/html/ilocplex13.html). I am completely new with c++, but hope to be able to get this running.

I am trying to compile it on linux. I am using the following command to run it

```
g++ -D IL_STD  -I /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/opl/include  ilolpex1.cpp
```

The -D IL_STD was put there to solve an error as found [here](https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21399983). The -I ... was put there to specify the location of the header files. I came up with this myself after a lot of trying and googling, so i am in no way sure this is correct.

Anyway, i when i run it i get errors of undefined references:

```
/tmp/ccl9O1YF.o: In function `populatebyrow(IloModel, IloNumVarArray, IloRangeArray)':
ilolpex1.cpp:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `IloNumVar::IloNumVar(IloEnv, double, double, IloNumVar::Type, char const*)'
```

I did not make any changes in the file, so i assume the only thing which can be wrong is how the files are linked. I have the feeling it probably just is a simple setting, but after hours of looking i still have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to compile the ilolpex1.cpp example is to use the Makefile that is included with the installation. For example, you should do the following:

```
$ cd /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/cplex/examples/x86-64_linux/static_pic
$ make ilolpex1
```

This will produce output, like the following:

```
g++ -O0 -c -m64 -O -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -I../../../include -I../../../../concert/include  ../../../examples/src/cpp/ilolpex1.cpp -o ilolpex1.o
g++ -O0 -m64 -O -fPIC -fno-strict-aliasing -fexceptions -DNDEBUG -DIL_STD -I../../../include -I../../../../concert/include  -L../../../lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -L../../../../concert/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic -o ilolpex1 ilolpex1.o -lconcert -lilocplex -lcplex -lm -lpthread
```

This will tell you everything you'll need to know if you choose to compile your own application by hand in the future. The details about this are described in the documentation (e.g., [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/GettingStarted/topics/set_up/GNU_Linux.html)).

Comment: When i do this it seems to work, but it places everything in clplex/examples.. . If i copy all the files there to my workspace and run it from there it says: No rule to make target 'iloplex1'

Comment: The Makefile depends on the relative location of the rest of the CPLEX installation. So, copying the files to your workspace will not work. You would also have to edit them. If you're not very familiar with Makefiles, it may be easier to copy the output from the Makefile that was successful for you and modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: I got it working! I copied the whole static_pic and in makefile i changed the directories at the top. Thanks a lot for your help! I know it is probably a simple thing for you, but i spent a full day trying to get cplex running and it is finally working. Again, thanks a lot, you have no idea how happy this makes me!

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the iloplex1.cpp file is just a demo how to *use* IloCplex.

What you yet need is IloCplex *itself*. This should come either as (a) further source file(s) you have to compile with the demo or as a library you link against.

Have a look at your cplex directories, you might find a `lib[...].a` file somewhere there, *possibly* in `/opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/opl/lib`.

You can link against using GCC's (clang's) [-l and -L options](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-l.html). Be aware that when using `-l`, you leave out `lib` and `.a` (`-l [...]` with above (invalid) sample name).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know it might sound obvious, but without any experience in c++ it is not. There are indeed some library files there, and i am trying to include them with: 

g++ -D IL_STD  -I /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/opl/include ilolpex1.cpp -L /opt/ibm/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1271/opl/lib/x86-64_linux/static_pic/  -l ilocplex  With this i still get the same errors though.

Comment: @user3053216 Library/code order can play a role. Try using `iloplex1.cpp` as the last parameter in the command line.